# How to extract json data from all events in the fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to be able to click on a button get all event data into one var of json objects containing all event data.

`$('#calendar').each(function(i,v){alert(v);});` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.fullCalendar('clientEvents')`. Returns an array of `Event` objects